# Spivak, Ch. 26, "Complex Functions": Understanding comments about differentiability of complex-valued functions.

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

In Chapter 26, "Complex Functions" of Spivak's *Calculus*, he introduces some concepts that were seen in the book up to this point (for real-valued functions defined for real numbers) to complex-valued functions.

For example,

- the concept of a limit, $\lim\limits_{z\to a} f(z)=l$
- the concept of continuity of a complex-valued $f$ at $a$, which means that $\lim\limits_{z\to a} f(z)=f(a)$
- the concept of a closed rectangle $[a,b]\times [c,d]$ on the complex plane as an analogue to the closed interval $[a,b]$ on the real line

He also states some claims without proving them

> If $f$ is a continuous complex-valued function whose domain is
> $[a,b]\times [c,d]$ then it seems reasonable, and is indeed true, that
> $f$ is bounded on $[a,b]\times [c,d]$, ie there is some real $M$ such that $|f(z)|\leq M$ for all $z$ in the closed rectangle.

Now, I'm not sure about this one, because he also mentions that it does not make sense to speak of an order for complex numbers. And $|f(z)|\leq M$ is actually the modulus of $f$.

**Is the quote correct as is?**

He then says that it does not make sense to say that $f$ has a maximum or minimum on the closed rectangle.

And finally he says that $f$ attains its maximum and minimum modulus on the closed rectangle. This part makes sense to me.

He then proceeds to give a proof of the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra, and then says

> Even taking into account our omission of the proofs for the basic
> facts about continuous complex functions, this proof verified a deep
> fact with surprisingly little work. It is only natural to hope that
> other interesting developments will arise if we pursue further the
> analogues of properties of real functions. The next obvious step is to
> define derivatives: a function $f$ is differentiable at $a$ if
>
> $$\lim\limits_{z\to 0} \frac{f(a+z)-f(a)}{z}$$
>
> exists, in which case the limit is denoted by $f'(a)$. It is easy to
> prove that
>
> $$f'(a)=0, \text{ if } f(z)=c$$ $$(...)$$ $$(f\circ
>  g)'(a)=f'(g(a))\cdot g'(a)$$
>
> the proofs of all these formulas are exactly the same as before. It
> follows, in particular, that if $f(z)=z^n$, then $f'(z)=nz^{n-1}$.
> **These formulas only prove the differentiability of rational functions**
> however. Many other obvious candidates are not differentiable.

I am really not sure where this part about rational functions is coming from.

I don't see where it was assumed $f$ was a rational function.

He then proceeds to give an example of a complex-valued function that is not differentiable at $0$, namely $f(x+iy)=x-iy$, ie $f(z)=\bar{z}$.

Irrespective of the example, I am looking for an explanation in more steps about how he went from defining a derivative for a complex-valued function, to saying its easy to prove certain analogues of properties already seen for real-valued functions, to then saying that these formulas only prove differentiability of rational functions.

Comment: To your question in bold face: the quote is correct as is, $|f(z)|$ is a real number.

Comment: $I=[a,b]\times[c,d]$ is compact; this is *reasonable* to expect that a continuous function $f$ (with values in $\mathbb{R}^m$, in particular $m=2$ for complex plane) on $I$ is bounded, i.e., the set $\{f(z):z\in I\}$ is covered by a ball around $0$, i.e.  $|f(z)|\leq M$ for some $M>0$ and all $x\in I$.

Comment: @Thomas Is it correct to say that $f$ is bounded?

Comment: yes, it's correct to say that $f$ is bounded on it's domain of definition, and the definition of that term is $|f(z)|$ is bounded for $z$ taken from that domain.

Comment: @OliverDíaz ok, I think I see the source of my confusion. When we have a real-valued function, we say that $|f|<M$ and this means $-M<f<M$, which means $f<M \land f>M$. But if $f$ is complex-valued, $f<M$ or $f>-M$ don't make sense.

Comment: So is it perhaps the case that for complex-valued $f$ we can't go from $|f|<M$ to $-M<f<M$?

Comment: @evianpring: In your future courses on multivariate Calculus and/or Complex variables you will see how many of the ideas from Calculus of on variable (Spivak's Calculus) are adapted to functions on many variables and with values on vector spaces ($\mathbb{R}^m$). Probably you can now graduate to  Spivak's Calculus on Manfolds, or Alfors's Complex Analysis.

Comment: @evianpring: $|f|=\sqrt{Re(f)^2+ Im(f)^2}$, that is $|f|$ is the modulus of $f$. In this context, a bounded set is one which can be covered by a disk (or ball) around the origin: $B(0;r)=\{z=z+iy: x^2+y^2< r^2\}$

Comment: Technically, there are *lots* of orders on $\mathbb C,$ but none of them are "good" the way that $\leq$ is good on $\mathbb R.$ The modulus order, $w\leq_m z$ iff $|w|\leq |z|$ in $\mathbb R$ has the property that, for some $w\neq z,$ it is possible for $w\leq_m z$ and $z\leq_m w.$ For this reason, we usually call $\leq_m$ a pre-order.

Comment: The key properties of the order on the real numbers is: (1) Every real $x,y$ $x\leq y$ or $y\leq x.$ (A total order.) (2) If $x\leq y$ and $z$ is real then $x+z\leq y+z.$ (3) If $x\leq y$ and $0\leq z,$ then $xz\leq yz.$

Comment: These properties give you a relationship between the order and the algebra of $\mathbb R.$ But there is no order on $\mathbb C$ which has the same relationship to the algebra on $\mathbb C.$

Comment: @OliverDíaz Indeed I am on the second to last chapter and will move on to an Analysis course (I guess the baby Rudin), and then Linear Algebra and then Manifolds. Manifolds is my ultimate goal right now. Didn't know about Alfor's, but definitely on the list now.

Comment: Well, inductively, he is saying the results given only prove rational functions are differentiable. He is not saying that there are no other functions are not differentiable, but that the given results he starts will only can be used to prove that all rational functions are differentiable, and that a lot of functions are not differentiable. When you get to other functions, like $e^z,$ which are differentiable, you will need to prove they are differentiable beyond these introductory results.

Comment: @evianpring: I personally like the term Baby Rudin as in chronological terms, Walter's first book (his baby) is Fourier Analysis on Groups, and then Principles...Anyway, I am sure that suffering through Spivak's Calculus will prepare you for the next step. I would always keep a proper Multivariate Calculus book at hand, for example Advanced Calculus' by Buck, or Courant's Calculus II and in addition to the Analysis Books.  One really need a good Calculus textbook to really get the intiotion, ideas and applications in place instead of jumping to abstractions right away.

Answer (score 1):

From the fact that:

1. The composition of two differentiable functions is differentiable.
2. The sum, the difference, the product and the quotient of two differentiable functions is differentiable.
3. The function$$z\mapsto z^n\tag1$$is differentiable for each $n\in\Bbb N$.

all that you can deduce is, yes, that each rational function is differentiable. That's because the set of all rational functions is precisely the set of those functions that can be obtained from the functions of the type $(1)$ through composition, sum, subtraction, multiplication, and division.

On the other hand, some very simple functions, such as real part, imaginary part, absolute value, and (as you know) conjugation are differentiable nowhere. And $z\mapsto|z|^2$ is differentiable at $0$ and only at $0$.

Answer (score 0):

The key to what Spivak is saying is that:

1. These initial theorems are only enough to classify a very small set of functions (the rational functions) as complex differentiable.
2. Unlike over the real numbers, being differentiable is a strong statement, and a *lot* of functions we can quickly write down are nowhere differentiable.

These two are really separate, unrelated claims.

He is not saying that there are no more complex differentiable functions. Just that, when looking at an arbitrary complex function, it tends to be less obvious if the function is a complex differentiable.

Spivak is saying these starting theorems only let you show that rational functions are all differentiable (where they are defined - $f(z)=\frac1z$ is not differentiable at $z=0,$ since $f(0)$ is not defined.)

---

(1) is actually true for real differentiable functions too - the equivalent real number theorems only let you prove that rational functions are real differentiable.

But in the real numbers, while there are certainly continuous function which are nowhere differentiable, most continuous functions we can easily write down are differentiable almost everywhere. There are functions like $|x|$ or $\sqrt{x}$ that are not differentiable at a point. But most that we encounter are "almost-everywhere" differentiable

This is not true for complex functions.

---

Over the complex numbers, we easily step into problems when we write our functions as $f(x+yi)=u(x,y)+v(x,y)i.$ There are tight restrictions on what $u$ and $v$ can be for $f$ to be differentiable.

Indeed, given $u,$ any two $v$ which make $f$ differentiable must differ by a constant. And, for "most" $u,$ there are no $v.$ For example, if $u(x,y)=x^2+y^2,$ there is no $v$ which makes $f$ complex differentiable.

And similarly, given $v,$ any two $u$ that work must differ by a constant, and for some $v$ there is no $u.$

---

You will, however, learn additional rules to classify other kinds of functions as differentiable. You will be able to define functions like $e^z,$ $\sin z,$ $\cos z,$ and prove they are continuous and complex differentiable.